# RVM: Why my Ruby on Rails project is still running with the Ruby version 1.9.3 even if I am using the 1.9.2?

Tags: ruby, apache, rvm, passenger

I am using Ruby on Rails 3.2.2 and RVM (Ruby Version Manager). By using RVM I installed 2 Ruby versions: first 1.9.3 and then 1.9.2. After I run the `rvm use --default 1.9.2` command line I closed and reopened the Terminal window. Finally I run the following command lines in the Terminal window:

```
$ which ruby
/<MY_USER_PATH>/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p318/bin/ruby

$ ruby -v
ruby 1.9.2p318 (2012-02-14 revision 34678) [x86_64-darwin10.8.0]
```

However, if I add the `<%= "Ruby version #{RUBY_VERSION}" %>` code in a view file of my Ruby on Rails project I get `Ruby version 1.9.3`.

**Why my Ruby on Rails project is still running with the Ruby version 1.9.3? How can I make that to run in Ruby 1.9.2?**

Comment: Do you have a `.rvmrc` file in your project directory?

Comment: How are you starting your app? What server?

Comment: @Andrew Marshall - I am using Apache with Virtual Hosts.

Comment: Okay, but how is Apache talking to Ruby? Via Passenger? Or is it proxying to mongrels or similar?

Comment: @Andrew Marshall - Via Passenger.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Passenger doesn't care about RVM, you need to compile Passenger with the Ruby version you want to use, and follow its instructions to setup Apache's configuration accordingly.

If you want to switch Ruby versions, you need to reinstall Passenger's Apache module via `passenger-install-apache-module` and follow the instructions.

You will likely see that the [`PassengerRuby`](http://modrails.com/documentation/Users%20guide%20Apache.html#PassengerRuby) directive in your Apache config is pointing to a specific `ruby`.

If you need different Ruby versions with Passenger, [Phusion's blog post](http://blog.phusion.nl/2010/09/21/phusion-passenger-running-multiple-ruby-versions/) on this may be helpful. [RVM's docs on Passenger integration](https://rvm.beginrescueend.com/integration/passenger/) are worth reading as well.

Answer (score 0):

I would guess that Apache (Passenger?) is using your globally installed version of Ruby, which looks like ruby 1.9.2. Do a `sudo su` and then try `which ruby` and see if you're still pointing to the RVM version of ruby. That version of Ruby is the one that Apache is using, you'd have to setup ruby globally to allow Apache (Passenger) to use it.